# JS. How to get list of div's with similar class name?

Tags: javascript, html

I have html, like this:

```
<div id="c0" class="bz_comment bz_first_comment"></div>
<div id="c1" class="bz_comment"></div>
<div id="c2" class="bz_comment"></div>
<div class="bz_add_comment"></div>
```

How can I get array of all the div's (3 div in example) by class that's starts with "bz_comment[anysymbols]" in JavaScript (not using JQuery)?

Or can i get array of div's by id that's starts with "c[numeric_value]"?

```
[numeric_value_can_consist_of_some_numbers]
```

It's the similar question like stackoverflow.com/questions/1225611/ (but i don't have reputation to ask in that question). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery?

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: If you don't need to worry about IE8 and below, you can do `document.querySelectorAll('[class*="bz_comment"]')`. This will give you all elements that have the characters "bz_comment" somewhere in the class string.

Comment: Are you two serious about the jQuery..?

Comment: Yup, serious. OP didn't tag jquery so you can't assume that

Comment: @hunter Do you see a jquery tag?

Comment: jQuery seems ubiquitous on the web these days. Just curious why OP doesn't want to use it.

Comment: @CoderDennis ...seriously?

Comment: Two users with 5K rep on the site recommending jQuery for something trivial that is a) as easy without jQuery and b) indicates a bigger much design problem. This is very saddening to see, makes me wish downvoting comments was possible.

Comment: @CoderDennis it's an 80 KB giant library with a lot of methods you probably don't need.

Comment: which is why I asked. my answer doesn't use jQuery

Comment: @hunter which I'm about to downvote unless you add an explanation...

Comment: You don't see me asking why he isn't using MooTools... Lay off jQuery for awhile kids.

Comment: @blackbird- welcome to SO! where asking for JS help often turns into the great jQuery debate! (go with Benjamins answer, it is correct).

Comment: I wasn't intending to recommend jQuery. OP mentioned specifically not using it and I wondered why. Next time I'll hold off on asking that.

Comment: @CoderDennis as a high rep user commenting on a question you should know that it weights in - it sounds like you're recommending jQuery, there is no problem with asking for clarification or reason for things in questions but for education's sake I'd really appreciate it if you could clarify more in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
var matching = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="bz_comment"]')
```

I see some worrying things in your code though:

- You have sequential numeric IDs, consider using an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to represent sequential data instead.
- You are selecting things by class name identifiers, if you must do this - use a [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute instead. Better yet, store the elements in an array instead and have a direct reference to them.

Comment: @RUJordan Actually, IE8 supports `.querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function to process elements on the page that contain the class you're looking for:

```
function containsClass(matchClassName) {
    var matches = new Array();
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClassName + ' ') > -1) {
           matches.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

now you can write

```
var matches = containsClass('bz_comment');
```

Comment: What's wrong with `document.querySelectorAll('[class*="bz_comment"]')` ?

Comment: @RUJordan no need to downvote a working solution for (really really) old browsers - he is just trying to help.

Comment: It's my tactic to get people to explain their answers. :D

Comment: Another fun fact is that you can use `[]` instead of `new Array()` whenever you're defining a new array.